# Extra Theme - Fit image inside of Featured Post Slider

Tags: posts, themes, images, slideshow

I'm building a website with Extra Theme and I'm having one problem. The Featured Posts Slider isn't fitting my images. I already search and try a lot of things but none of them work.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Featured Posts Slider is a plugin or theme functionality? can you share your url / snapshot?

Comment: It's a theme functionality. [Image](http://i.imgur.com/rY6Mtgl.png)

Comment: did you tried using `!important` ?

Comment: Yes I did , but still the same :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem in the easiest way. I installed the Revolution Slider, and I used the Code Module with the Revolution Slider short code. Thank you for all the answers!!

Answer (score 0):

Is it a problem with your images sliding between different sizes or the aspect ratio being off?

If it's the first, many themes use a add_image_size() function for the slider and any uploaded image that is smaller than either the width and height of this size will not function correctly within the slider. If this is the case, you will need larger sized images to make the slider work.

If this isn't the problem, please give more explanation of the incorrect behavior or a screenshot.